# ImportError: cannot import name 'cmdoptions' from 'pip._internal.cli'

Tags: python, django, pip, importerror

Has anyone seen this particular error, "ImportError: cannot import name 'cmdoptions' from 'pip._internal.cli'"?

This preventing any pip installs.

Is there a fix for this.  I am currently running python 3.8.

Thanks!!

Comment: Solved.  I recreated a virtual environment and reinstalled from the requirements text.